# How to search sub arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this MongoDB collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("123"), "from_name" : "name", "from_email" : "email@mxxxx.com", "to" : [  {  "name" : "domains",  "email" : "domains@xxx.com" } ], "cc" : [ ], "subject" : "mysubject" }
```

My goal is to search in this collection by the "to" with some email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want **one** field then MongoDB has ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) for accessing nested elements:

```js
db.collection.find({ "to.email": "domains@example.com" })
```

And this will return documents that match:

For *more* that one field as a condition, use the **`$elemMatch`** operator

```js
db.collection.find(
    { "to": { 
        "$elemMatch": { 
            "email": "domains@example.com",
            "name": "domains",
        }
    }}
)
```

And you can "project" a *single* match to just return that element:

```js
db.collection.find({ "to.email": "domains@example.com" },{ "to.$": 1 })
```

But if you expect **more** than *one* element to match, then you use the aggregation framework:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Matches the "documents" that contain this
    { "$match": { "to.email": "domains@example.com" } },

    // De-normalizes the array
    { "$unwind": "$to" },

    // Matches only those elements that match
    { "$match": { "to.email": "domains@example.com" } },

    // Maybe even group back to a singular document
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "from_name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "to": { "$push": "$to" },
        "subject": { "$first": "$subject" }            
    }}

])
```

All fun ways to match on and/or "filter" the content of an array for matches if required.